# How to reverse direction of moving div once it reaches side of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an absolutely positioned div that uses the jQuery .animate function to move horizontally from the right to left of the screen.
My problem is that once the div reaches the far left side, it continues and eventually disappears from the screen. How do you make it so that once the div reaches the left side, it will reverse and start going to the right? (and then vice versa so that the right side won't continue going right, but goes left again once it reaches the end)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    right:100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.block').click(function() {
    $(this).animate(
        {"right": "+=100px"},"slow");
});
```

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebkc9dzL/

Thank you I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You might want to start by thinking about *collision detection*. jQuery offers a [number of plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/collision/).

Comment: You can use a variable to compare with it and check on a conditional. If the right is greater than that variable then do nothing, if is slower then animate it

Comment: side of the browser, not side of the screen you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebkc9dzL/19/

You need to have a variable outside the click function that will tell you the direction of the animation, so that once inside the click function you can calculate the location of the animated object using `getBoundingClientRect()` ([mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)).

Then, if object is moving left and its `left` distance is less than its own width, you need to move it only enough so that it comes to the edge. If it's AT the edge (`left` is zero), you need to change the direction.

If it's moving right and its `right` distance is less than its own width, you need to move it only enough (calculated by `window.innerWidth - 100`, since 100 is width of your object) so that it comes to the edge. If it's AT the right edge, you need to change direction.

Changing direction in object you pass to jQuery's `animate` function is a simple matter of adding or subtracting from its "right" attribute.

```
var direction = "+";
$('.block').click(function() {
    var obj = {},
        distance = 100,
        rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();

    if(direction=="+"){
        if(rect.left>0 && rect.left < 100)
            distance = rect.left;
        else if(rect.left<=0)
            direction = "-";
    }
    else {
        if(rect.right >(window.innerWidth-100) && rect.right+1<window.innerWidth)
            distance = (window.innerWidth-rect.right);
        else if(rect.right+1 >=window.innerWidth){
            direction = "+";
        }
    }

    obj = {"right": direction+"="+distance.toString()+"px"}
    $(this).animate(obj,"slow");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

may be you should try like this:

```
$('.block').click(function() {
    var leftPosition = $(this).position();
    if (leftPosition.left > 100) {
        $(this).animate({"right": "+=100px"},"slow");
    } else {
        $(this).animate({"right": "-=100px"},"slow");
    }
});
```

when the element is close to the border the `if..else` part of the code will reverse the direction.

Here is a fiddle, try to click on the red box to get an idea on how it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/dimitrioglo/ebkc9dzL/14/

Comment: I meant somthing like this, if you dont understand me

https://jsfiddle.net/dimitrioglo/ebkc9dzL/14/

Comment: of course you need to improve this solution, but it is the main idea

Comment: @D.Dimitrioglo your answer has been flagged as low-quality. Why do you not copy the code of your fiddle (just the js code) inside your answer and provide some details on how it works?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebkc9dzL/15/).

The new javascript is as follows:

```
var goLeft = true;  
$('.block').click(function() {
    var animateDist = 100;

    var distLeft = $(this).position().left;
    var distRight = window.innerWidth - distLeft;

    if (goLeft) {
        if (distLeft < 100) {
            animateDist = "+="+distLeft+"px";
            $(this).animate(
                {"right": animateDist},"slow"
            );
            goLeft = false;
        } else {
            $(this).animate(
                {"right": "+=100px"},"slow"
            );
        }
    } else {
        if (distRight < 100) {
            animateDist = "-="+distRight+"px";
            $(this).animate(
                {"right": animateDist},"slow"
            );
            goLeft = true;
        } else {
            $(this).animate(
                {"right": "-=100px"},"slow"
            );
        }
    }
});
```

This isn't perfect, you need to adjust your internal window width to match the parent container, but this is enough to get you in the right direction.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var sign = [ "+" , "-" ];
var signPosition = 0;
var maxOffset = $(".block").offset().left;
$('.block').click(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().left < 100) {
        signPosition = 1;
    } else if ($(this).offset().left == maxOffset) {
        signPosition = 0;
    }
    $(this).animate(
        {"right": sign[signPosition] + "=100px"},"slow");
});
```

The variable `sign` is the array that contains the directions in which the element might move, the variable `signPosition` contains the position of the direction currently in use, the variable `maxOffset` contains the starting position.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The code doesn't reach left side of the screen, and doesn't reverse after right side is reached. Fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/ebkc9dzL/20/